# Does Bitbucket allow you to "View blame prior to this change", like in Github?

Tags: github, bitbucket

On Github, when you blame a file, you can see all the commits, annotated on the left hand side. They also have a very helpful link called "View blame prior to this change", which allows you to go to the blame of the same file **prior** to the commit you clicked on:

**In Github:**
[image: View blame prior to this change]

It allows you to very quickly traverse the git history of a file, and get to the root cause of a bug/problem.

Is there an equivalent feature in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on `bitbucket.org`.

There is an ["annotate" option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128935/6309) for the blame view, but without the "prior to this change" feature.

Each annotate line has its own commit reference: you can click on that commit, then diff, and you will see what was before that commit. Not as straightforward as GitHub.

Comment: Yeah I was worried that's the case. I think I'll pursue traversing git history using the IDE instead then, which is more powerful that that. A shame though - Github's done well with that feature, also showing the commit comment inline too.